# How to force post back on submission

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, postback

I have an old asp.net webforms project, and there is some confusion because some of the validation error messages appear when you click 'submit' if they are client side validations.  And once those client side validation errors are fixed, then the user will see the validation errors that get validated on the server-side.

Is it possible to force the submit button to go to the server side so all the errors are displayed?

Comment: Could the server side validation be done on the client side as well? That would be your best bet if it can be done easily enough.

Comment: @TonyL. no it can't, it does database lookups and other custom logic.

Comment: I suppose you could use a web method to do it. The problem you will have is that once you cause a full postback, your page gets completely rebuilt and all of your client-side validation would be gone. I suppose another option would be to do all of the validation on the server-side.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the validators that are validating client side, set EnableClientScript="false" so it doesn't validate using javascript